# Forced rename update function (sku number input > url key input)

Tags: magento2, product, php, sku, url-key

How do I code a function that force sku input data into url-key input data everytime I update a simple product or groupe product?

This code work only on product creation but I want it to work on product update too.
ProductUrlPathGenerator.php

```
<?php 
namespace Developer\Module\Model;

/**
 * Class AbstractAction
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/

class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator {

    protected function prepareProductDefaultUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $storedProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
        $storedUrlKey = $storedProduct->getUrlKey();
        return $storedUrlKey ?: $product->formatUrlKey($storedProduct->getSku());
    }



    protected function prepareProductUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
        return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getSku() : $urlKey);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with help from a friend

```
<?php 
namespace Developer\Module\Model;

/**
 * Class AbstractAction
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/

class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator {

    protected function prepareProductDefaultUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $storedProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
        $storedUrlKey = $storedProduct->getUrlKey();
        return $storedUrlKey ?: $product->formatUrlKey($storedProduct->getSku());
    }



    protected function prepareProductUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        if($product->getSku()!='') {
            return $product->getSku();
        }
        $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
        return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getSku() : $urlKey);
    }
}
```